# Hide certain characters in Sharepoint people picker field

Tags: javascript, infopath, people-picker

I have a people picker field that is supposed to pull the current user of the infopath form's name and so far it works fine, but when exported to excel it also pulls in some extraneous characters that I don't want my users to see.

Is there a way to hide them? I am unable to set the default value of the field so I can't use the translate function and I am unable to write custom code in the form itself so any way aside from those would be helpful.

Here is an example of what I get on export: Doe, John***;#94***

The characters in the italics are the ones I need removed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can fix this issue in SharePoint side. The best option is to create some script in Excel to remove this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023686/cleaning-people-group-data-exported-from-sharepoint-2010-lists

Comment: Hi @AmalHashim, that is fine but how do I have the script run automatically whenever users want to export the list to excel? Is that possible?

Comment: I believe you need to work out with your IT department and push this script every workstation.. inside the script first you should identify if data is coming from SharePoint export.. then identify people/lookup columns and clean it up. I don't see any other options for automating this.